# How do i list items with an object through one page to another. (Jquery & Ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, object

Help to find a way to use an object for each:
like object.nomes etc.

How do i list items with an object through one page to another. (Jquery & Ajax)

```
$.fn.gerarResumo = function(ajax){

// produto = new object();*****

nomes       = new Array();
precos      = new Array();
quantidades = new Array();
codigosNcm  = new Array();

var tipoEmbarque       = $(".tipoEscolhidoEmbarque").val();
var nomes              = $(".produtosNome").val();
var produtosPreco      = $(".produtosPreco").val();
var produtosQuantidade = $(".produtosQuantidade").val();
var produtosCodigosNcm = $(".produtosCodigosNcm").val();
var qtdProdutoGerado   = $(".qtdProdutoGerado").val();
//var tipoFrete        = $(".tipoFreteSelecionado").val();

var valorFrete         = $(".valorFreteSelecionado").val();
var textoHtml = "";

$(".natureza").text(tipoEmbarque);

$(".incoterm").html("FRETE: EXW/FOB/FAS <br> Valor do Frete: "+valorFrete+" USD");

nomes       = produtosNome.split(',');
precos      = produtosPreco.split(',');
quantidades = produtosQuantidade.split(',');
codigosNcm  = produtosCodigosNcm.split(',');

for(i=1; i<nomes.length; i++){

    if(!ajax){
        if(nomes[i] != ""){
            $(".painel-resumo").append("<div class='titleitens'>Item "+i+"</div><div class='detalhesitem'>Produto: "+nomes[i]+" <br> Preço: "+precos[i]+" USD <br> Quantidade: "+quantidades[i]+" <br> NCM: "+codigosNcm[i]+"</div>");  
        }               
    }else{
        textoHtml += "<div class='titleitens'>Item "+i+"</div><div class='detalhesitem'>Produto: "+nomes[i]+" <br> Preço: "+precos[i]+" USD <br> Quantidade: "+quantidades[i]+" <br> NCM: "+codigosNcm[i]+"</div>";
    }           
}

if(ajax){
    return textoHtml; 
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [foreach equivalent of php in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198436/foreach-equivalent-of-php-in-jquery)

Comment: (Code blocks need an additional indent by for blanks - or, in the post editor, mark the block and use "the `{}`-button" or type <Ctrl-K>.)

Comment: Hello, so the problem is when a send the array itens i wanna split Like:
ex:
NCM 1: 3232323

Comment: Ncm 1: 32323  product 1: name, qtd, - Product2: name, qtd
Ncm 2: 44444 Produtc 1: name, qtd -  product 2: name, qtd
and on and on....

Comment: the problem is when i send to other page the itens get mixed>